# What is json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, api, curl

I am requesting a face comparing API. Where you send 2 pictures and it return if they are the same person or not Here is the link:
[Face++ API](https://www.faceplusplus.com/face-comparing/#demo)

In the documentation, they mentioned you can request it like this:

```
curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/compare" \
-F "api_key=<api_key>" \
-F "api_secret=<api_secret>" \
-F "face_token1=c2fc0ad7c8da3af5a34b9c70ff764da0" \
-F "face_token2=ad248a809408b6320485ab4de13fe6a9"
```

Here is my code:

```
result = json.loads(os.popen('curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/compare/api_key=myKey/api_secret=mySecret/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic33.jpg/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic39.jpg"').read())
```

But when I run it, I am getting this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/Programming/Face/venv/face.py", line 15, in <module>
    result = json.loads(os.popen('curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/compare/api_key=myKey/api_secret=mySecret/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic33.jpg/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic39.jpg"').read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried to do in another way, using requests:

```
result = requests.get( "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/compare/api_key=myKey/api_secret=mySecret/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic33.jpg/https://us-mc-prod-asset.oss-us-west-1.aliyuncs.com/mc-official/scripts/demoScript/images/demo-pic39.jpg")
```

But, I am getting this:

```
<Response [404]>
```

Comment: It means there was an error decoding the JSON because there was extra data the parser didn't know how to deal with. Presumably the API doesn't return a single valid JSON object, but you'd have to look at what actually gets downloaded to determine that.

Comment: what is the output of the `os.popen(' ... ').read()` call? like Jon said, I suspect it's not JSON

Comment: Thanks everyone. @sam I added the output for os.popen(..).read()

Answer (score 1):

The curl command is malformed, and as such, you are getting the error `Could not resolve host: api_key=myKey` instead of valid JSON return data.

However, (not to derail from your question), may I suggest that you use something like `requests` (or `urllib2` if you must use a standard python library) to send the HTTP request. Invoking curl the way that you are will produce unexpected results such as what you are dealing with right now.

Furthermore, `requests` actually has a very handy `json()` method for response objects. This will make your code cleaner and easier to troubleshoot. Here is an example from the docs:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content

Comment: Thank you so much. To my understanding I can use requests where I do not have to provide api key and other entries. Moreover, in the api docs mentioned use 'curl' to get the results. But still i tried to use requests and the result is <Response [404]> which is not found. Appreciate your suggestions!

Comment: No worries, can you post your requests code sample (redacted of course)? Will try to help out.

Comment: Thanks man, that is appreciated! I added everything you may need.